# ChromeDriver won't start

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using **Selenium3** as we know there have been modifications made to FireFox (it used to be a straightforward call), now we have to set it in property pointing at the geckodriver.

I am using **chrome driver** but getting the error:

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property.
```

here is m code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;


public class DriverTest {
//@Test
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\right\\pathHere\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

//Navigate to URL
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

}

Comment: Change the key from `webdriver.gecko.driver` (firefox) to `webdriver.chrome.driver` (Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

try using this path:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\right\\pathHere\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

**geckodriver** driver works with **FireFox** browser. So you should have **FireFox** installed in your PC. Then download the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and keep it to the location `C:\Users\right\pathHere\`

Now set **geckodriver** using **setProperty()** method like below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\right\\pathHere\\geckodriver.exe");
```